# ADODB connection refuses to connect due to missing operator

Tags: sql, ms-access, adodb

I'm opening an excel sheet via ADODB connection. The code has been working fine, until today, when it refused to connect to a new excel file.

The SQL string I am using is:

```
SELECT container_key, 
       price_catalogue, 
       portfolio_type, 
       portfolio_subtype, 
       yearly_fee, 
       yearly_fee_factor, 
       yearly_fee_2, 
       value_1, 
       advisory_agreement__advisory, 
       value_1_29, 
       3rd_party_key 
FROM   [temp0$]
```

Now I get an error message from VBA when i am on the line that is supposed to open the recordset:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '3rd_party_key'

I have verified that the field exists and is named the same in the spreadsheet. The syntax looks correct to me as well. The spreadhseet is extremly large (360+ columns) and the field that is refrenced in the error message is the very last column. Might this have somethingto do with the issue I am encountering?

Can someone point out what the problem might be?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried putting all field names in parentheses. While this worked in not producing a run time error and it didn't work either. Finally I tried reducing the number of fields and went one by one. The following 3 fields cause the errors:

```
   advisory_agreement__advisory, 
   value_1_29, 
   3rd_party_key
```

If i remove these fields, I can open the recordset without a problem. I suspect the name conventions of these fields causes a conflict somehow.

Comment: Just a guess, but try wrapping the field name in square brackets as `[3rd_party_key]`. I think that Access doesn't like fields starting with numbers......

Comment: Intersting to know... and it seems that it does eliminate that error, though now a new one is genereated "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Comment: No idea about the new error. Does the field `advisory_agreement__advisory` actually have a double underline in?

Comment: Yes it does have a double underline. I also tested the hypothesis that the problem is the number further, by removing the numeral in the field name. It does seem to make a difference, but i continue to get the error: "No value given for one or more required parameters".

Comment: Double and triple check the names of the fields

Comment: I tested your column headers. Only had to enclose 3rd_party_key in brackets. Also, using `*` instead of specifying names works but had only 3 columns.

Comment: You put field names in brackets, not parentheses?

Comment: I did put them in brackets... didn't work. I have been investigating this all day and it seems the size of the worksheet (ie # of columns) is also playing a part in this. I'm done for today but will be back on the case monday. Nevertheless, thanks for your help today!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it column by column, with square brackets, to see which column is actually causing the problem. It might seem a bit tedious but this way you will know exactly where the problem lies.